# Match a comma delimited string to an integer list using linq and return the new objects

Tags: c#, linq

Edit: I changed my inputs from a

```
List<string>
```

to a `List<int>`. They should always be valid integers now, no empty/null etc.

I currently have a 6 item list, the items consistent of integers.

I also have an object that contains a coma delimited string of integers. I'm trying to match the inputs to this list.

---

For example

Inputs could be, 1000,2000,3000
The object contains 1000,2000,3000,4000
I would want this to match.

If my input is 1000,2000,3000,4000 and my object only contains 1000,2000,3000 -> it should not match.

Here's my current code to create the object using linq to xml. "TaxUnitIdList" is the comma delimited string. (This is when my inputs were strings)

```
var   obj = (from tug in tugElem.Descendants("CodeData")
select new TaxUnitGroups
{
    Code = (string)tug.Attribute("code"),
    CodeID = (string)tug.Attribute("codeid"),
    Desc = (string)tug.Attribute("desc"),
    TaxUnitIdList = (string)tug.Attribute("taxunits")
});
```

I'm thinking something along the following or a join (which I could not get to work) this is failing me due to the where wanting a boolean (which makes sense)

```
var matchedTugs = (from tug in tugElem.Descendants("CodeData")
    let TaxUnitIdList = (string)tug.Attribute("taxunits")
    let taxArr = TaxUnitIdList.Split(',').Select(int.Parse)
    where taxArr.Contains(inputTaxUnits.All()) //This is where I screw up
    select new TaxUnitGroups
    {
        Code = (string)tug.Attribute("code"),
        CodeID = (string)tug.Attribute("codeid"),
        Desc = (string)tug.Attribute("desc"),
        TaxUnitIdList = (string)tug.Attribute("taxunits")
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the Where clause:

```
TaxUnitIdList.Split(',')
    .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
    .Except(inputTaxUnits.Where(s=>int.TryParse(s, out tempInteger))
        .Select(s=>int.Parse(s)))
    .Any();
```

Basically, we want to covert the `TaxUnitId` list into an integer array, convert the input list into a **good** (tryparse) input array as well, find the difference and verify that the result is 0.

Comment: I believe that the example you provided is matching on anything due to the "All" keyword? I may be going about this problem totally wrong...